# Mac OS X - Apache path? Ruby on Apache?

Tags: apache, macos

I can activate an apache webserver in the System Preferences. Now I want to install some mods but I can't find the path. Everybody suggests it is /usr/local/apache, but that doesn't exist. Where can I find my apache path to install the mods?

Thanks,
MrB

[edit]

Specifically, I want to install Ruby integration so I can include <% %> Ruby tags in my HTML. If anyone has any hints on how to do this, or tutorials, please say so. All the Ruby folks seem to be using Mongrel, but I have apache and want it to work there, if possible. Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Mac OS X 10.6, the modules are located in `/usr/libexec/apache2`.

You can look into the configuration file in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf to figure out the path if you're not finding them there.

As for using ruby you can use [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) to install FastCGI. Follow the [instructions to install MacPort](http://www.macports.org/install.php) and then run:

```
port install fcgi
```

Using MacPorts you get the benefit of easy updates (`port selfupdate; port upgrade outdated`
)

Comment: That links to eRuby, which hasn't been updated since 2004 and doesn't compile on my 10.6. Thanks though. Any other ideas? I'm trying mod_fcgid after this http://nexus.zteo.com/blog/2007/01/28/how-to-add-rubyrails-to-your-existing-apache-setup/ but it can't find the "build" folder in the apache dir..

Comment: You can use macports fcgi (easiest) to install fcgi. I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Ok I've done that. Now how do I tell my apache to use fcgi? I activated mod_fastcgi in httpd.conf, but it doesn't work yet. Any hints? It says in that tutorial that you should add /cgi-bin/eruby to httpd.conf. Do I have to add something like /cgi-bin/fcgi? Where is cgi-bin? Can't find it in the folders you guys recommended.

Answer (score 1):

The config files are in `/private/etc/apache2/` on my system (Mac OS 10.6). The apachectl script is in `/usr/sbin/apachectl`. The actual httpd binary is in `/usr/sbin/httpd`.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be it. But when I run the fcgid makefile with that configured, he can't find a "build" folder that seems to be expected there.

Comment: Any ideas? (more words la la wtf is up with this UI)

Answer (score 0):

The conf files are located in /private/etc/apache2 and the mod files are in /usr/libexec/apache2